# How to add checkBox for variables group with tabPanel in R shiny

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I need help in adding variables checkbox in r shiny within the tabPanel. I have already developed an r shiny app, in which on one of the page the data is displayed on the basis of some filterers and keywords search box.

So, I want to include one checkbox group of variables for the uploaded file. 
I saw some of the solution but, non of them is based on tabPanel. Is it possible to have variable checkBox with tabPanel and how to place this under UI and SERVER. Also, as rest of the development is done so, would like to have solution with tabPanel if possible. Thanks

Tried adding the checkBoxInput but with not working with tabPanel and disturbing the current tabPanel

Below is my UI and SERVER

Here, the complete code is not displayed but, with following ui and server, wanted to add checkBoxInputgroup of variable and it should take the variable values from dfcase().

```
ui <- tabPanel('Evidence Finder in Background Text',

selectizeInput("Words1",

label="Important Words - Dictionary",

 choices= TRUE,
 multiple = TRUE,
 options = list(maxOptions = 20000)),

 DT::dataTableOutput("table2")
 )


 output$table2 <- DT::renderDataTable(server = FALSE,{

 dfcase_bckg = as.data.frame(dfcase())

 DT::datatable(dfcase_bckg,
          rownames = FALSE,
          escape = TRUE,
          class = 'cell-border stripe',
          selection = "single",
          extensions = 'Buttons',
          )
}
)
```

[This is the view of the app and to left side i need the list of variables with checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2GUO.png)

Comment: Could you provide a reproductible example of what you tried or something else (picture ...) to help understand what you want to do ?

Comment: Have updated the question and added one tabPanel and server associated with it. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example
Some fake content of the dataset and a runable shiny app would be appreciate.

Comment: Actually, i can not share complete app but i will post some screenshot of the thing.

Comment: the complete app is not necessary but just an runable code would help you to get anwsers

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of the app